# Parameter with question mark and super

Tags: java

In Java, I've come across a method that is formatted like this:

```
public final Subscription subscribe(final Action1<? super T> onNext, final Action1<Throwable> onError) {
}
```

In the first parameter, what does the question mark and super mean?

Comment: `?` is a generic wildcard ... have you searched for this before posting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java

Comment: ... have you seen the StackOverflow **Documentation** on Java? It discusses `? super T` vs. `? extends T` in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` here means everything that is a superclass of `T`

`super` means what you can put into the class (at most this, perhaps a superclass).

Because `super` indicates the lower bounding class of a generic element. So, `Action1<? super T>` could represent `Action1<T>` or `Action1<Object>`.